# Python 3 Appending to a list value of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

```
import re


ports = {}
file = open("Asn1_TCPdump_format3.txt")



def makerPorts(src, port, ports):
    if src in ports:
        ports[src][0].append(port)
    else:
        ports[src] = [port]

    return ports



for k, v in ports.items():
    print(k, v)
```

What i'm trying to do here is make a dictionary where the KEY is the IP address and the value is a list of the ports each ip address is trying to connect to. I feel like this should be really simple but am having a hard time wrapping my head around this ?

My Regex is all fine the part that is broken is the makerPort Function, i want the function to take a an ip, a port, and a dictionary. it than checks the dictionary if the ip is a key and if it is than it adds the port to the list of ports. If the IP is not yet a key it adds the ip as a key and the port as the value in a list

Comment: It looks, from the `else` statement, as if your dictionary is of the form d = {ip1: [port11, port12], ip2: [port21, port22, port23]}. If so, your `if` statement is strange, since you're trying to `append` to a number (`port[src][0]` is a number, not a list).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct, you just have to drop the `[0]` from `ports[src][0]`. The reason is that the keys values in the `ports` dict are all lists of integers representing the ports each ip (keys of the dict) connect to.

As such, selecting a specific value of port by doing something like `port["127.0.0.1"]` would give you a list like `[80, 8080]`. By doing `port["127.0.0.1"][0]` you are selecting the first item of that list, in this case, `80`. Consequently, by doing `port["127.0.0.1"][0]` you are effectively calling `80.append()`, which causes your code to fail, since append() is a list method.

A working version would look something like this:

```
>>> ports = {}
>>> def makerPorts(src, port, ports):
...    if src in ports:
...        ports[src].append(port)
...    else:
...        ports[src] = [port]
...
...    return ports
... 
>>> makerPorts("1.0.0.1",80,ports)
>>> makerPorts("1.0.0.1",40,ports)
>>> makerPorts("1.0.0.2",40,ports)
>>> makerPorts("1.0.0.3",80,ports)
>>> makerPorts("1.0.0.3",40,ports)
>>> print( ports )
{'1.0.0.2': [40], '1.0.0.1': [80, 40], '1.0.0.3': [80, 40]}
```